# How do I solve $\lim_{n\to \infty} \int_{1\over n}^{n} {{\arctan(x^2)}\over1+x^2}dx$

Tags: integration, limits, trigonometry

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \int_{1\over n}^{n} {{\arctan(x^2)}\over1+x^2}dx$$
Can someone explain me how to solve this limit? Thank you!

Comment: Is the numerator supposed to be $\arctan(x^2)$? Also, I swear I saw this same integral yesterday or the day before on this site

Comment: yes, it is. i will search it, thank you!

Comment: You can use the substitution $x \mapsto 1/x$ to check that $$ \int_{1/n}^{n} \frac{\arctan (x^2)}{1+x^2} \, dx
= \int_{1/n}^{n} \frac{\frac{\pi}{2} - \arctan (x^2)}{1+x^2} \, dx, $$ from which the integral is evaluated as $$ \int_{1/n}^{n} \frac{\arctan (x^2)}{1+x^2} \, dx = \frac{\pi}{4}\left( \frac{\pi}{2} - 2\arctan\frac{1}{n^2}\right). $$

Answer (score 1):

As @SangchulLee has posted in a comment since I begun, we can note that
$$I=\int_0^\infty \frac{\arctan(x^2)}{x^2+1} = \int_0^\infty \frac{\arctan\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right)}{x^2+1}$$
We add the two together, using the rule $\arctan(x) +\arctan(1/x) = \pi /2$
$$2I = \int_0^\infty \frac{\frac{\pi}{2}}{x^2+1}$$

Comment: Let it be noted that typing MathJax on mobile is awful. Simply awful.

Comment: It's not. I do it all the time.

Comment: @ParclyTaxel It's pretty awful (at least with an iPhone)

Comment: @ParclyTaxel so do I. Doesn't mean it's easy by any means... Takes three times as long as if I had a good keyboard nearby. Almost makes me want to invest in a pocket sized keyboard XD